# Получить HANDLE файла

Tags: c, windows, файлы, winapi

Как я могу получить `HANDLE` файла по его `FILE*`, искал в сети, но ничего должного не нашел, только реализации для `POSIX`.

ОC: Windows x32-64
Тулчейн MinGW64

```
HANDLE hFile = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fileno(fopen("test.txt", "r")));
DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

if (dwSize == 0xFFFFFFFF)
{
    perror("Invalid provided handle.");
}

printf("%d", (unsigned long)dwSize);
```

Comment: Способ, разумеется, зависит от реализации. И чем плох приведенный вами код? Все вроде прекрасно работает. Что вы имеете в виду под "реализациями для POSIX", когда в MSVC тоже поддерживается `fileno`? Или вам не для MSVC?

Comment: У вас `GetFileSize` используется совершенно неверно. Она будет возвращать неправильный размер для любого файла размером 4Гб и более, плюс к тому, ваша программа будет печатать ложное сообщение об ошибке если файл имеет размер `(n * 2^32) + (2^32 - 1)` - потому что возвращаемое значение `0xFFFFFFFF` необязательно сигнализирует об ошибке.

Comment: @freim я понял, а как более правильно написать данный код? Можете привести пример или кинуть ссылку на статью, буду очень благодарен

Comment: @AnT забыл уточнить, у меня mingw64 тулчейн стоит, данный код работает, но я думаю что не совсем корректно, есть некоторые варны, и как подметил freim если файл более 4 гб эта функция не сработает

Comment: @Mothership Не понял. Я вижу вопрос о том, как получить HANDLE файла. Вариант с `_get_osfhandle(fileno(` прекрасно работает. Замечания freim к теме получения HANDLE никакого отношения не имеют. Если ваш вопрос о чем-то другом - то сформулируйте его по-другому, чтобы было понятно, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вы задайте другой вопрос, и я приведу вам код. В комментарий код не вставляется, а в ответах нельзя писать на другую тему. У вас же вопрос про `HANDLE`, а не про `GetFileSize`.